# PostgreSQL error: language "plperlu" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plperl

I am a beginner with PostgreSQL. I got a SQL patch of PostgreSQL and while executing the SQL to configure it at my end.  I am getting following error. My background is MySQL.

#### Query

```
CREATE FUNCTION wine_entry_script() RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plperlu AS
$$
   #!/usr/bin/perl -w
   use strict;
   require ('/var/lib/pgsql/data/Trigger_Processor1.0.pl');
$$;
```

#### Error

> ERROR: language "plperlu" does not exist SQL state: 42704 Hint: Use
>   CREATE LANGUAGE to load the language into the database.

Comment: `plperlu`? Is that a typo? Furthermore, the syntax is not correct, a good starting point would be the basic function body as in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl-funcs.html)

Comment: @DrColossos: `plperlu` is [not a typo](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plperl-trusted.html).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Wasn't aware of that, good info though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`plperlu` is the [untrusted version of PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plperl-trusted.html) (`plperl`). It is one of the prepared choices in PostgreSQL. Have a look:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_language;
```

To use it, run once per database:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

You must be superuser to *install* any additional language. You must be superuser to *use* untrusted languages. Be aware of security implications! [More in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xplang-install.html)

Most Linux systems come with Perl installed. Under Windows, make sure that [some flavor of Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Windows) is installed in your system (providing the required DLL files) *before* you can create the language.

Related:

- [Create Language plperl - Error: could not load library plperl.dll](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47839/create-language-plperl-error-could-not-load-library-plperl-dll)

Comment: thanks Erwin. Whlile executing CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu; I am gettingERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.1/lib/plperl.dll": The specified module could not be found. does that means I need to install it ?
SQL state: 58P01

Comment: @testingdeveloper: The required perl module is obviously not found where postgres would expect it. I don't know much about the windows build. You might have to install an appropriate version of perl first.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error: could not load library "C:/Program Files (x86)/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/plperl.dll

Comment: @Anvesh: I added some hints for Windows above.

Answer (score 4):

create the extension and then the language.

```
CREATE EXTENSION plperl;
CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you install plperl in your server by below command

```
sudo apt install postgresql-plperl-13
```

(Change 13 with your current version)

now login with postgres

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Now you login with database which require this extension

```
psql -d nameofdatabase

CREATE EXTENSION plperl;

CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;
```

Now its ready for use